# C2027: use of undefined type Foo::Impl

Tags: c++

ALL,

```
class __declspec(dllexport) MyClass
{
protected:
    struct Impl;
    Impl *pimpl;
public:
    Impl &GetStruct() { return pimpl; }
    const std::wstring &GetName() { return pimpl->m_name; };
};

struct MyClass::Impl
{
    std::wstring m_name;
};
```

Is there a reason why GetName() is throwing the error and GetStruct() does not? And how do I modify the code in order to compile?

TIA!!

Comment: `Impl` and `Foo` are unrelated!

Comment: @CinCout, sorry I fixed the code. Any idea?

Comment: `Impl &GetStruct() { return pimpl; }` is a compiler error, presumably it should be `Impl &GetStruct() { return *pimpl; }`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the C++ parser works from top to bottom. At the end of the `MyClass` declaration, the nested `Impl` has not been fully defined. It was declared ("there is a struct Impl") but the full definition ("struct Impl looks as following ...") only comes later. However, in order to generate code for `pimpl->m_name`, the compiler needs to know more, in particular it needs to know what type `m_name` is and at what offset to its containing `Impl` it is located.

In short, you stumbled across a well-known limitation of the PIMPL idiom, namely that you can't use inline functions as you are used to.

Answer (score 0):

At the point where you request `pimpl->m_name`, it is not known yet that there's a thing named `m_name` inside the thing that `pimpl` points to. Technically, `pimpl` is a pointer to an *incomplete type*. It becomes complete when its definition is seen.

So you need to move the definition of `GetName` out of tye class and to some point after the definition of `MyClass::Impl`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I intended to add an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to [Ulrichs sufficient answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52418218/7478597) but while trying to get it running on coliru I found some more issues:

1. `MyClass::GetStruct()` has return type `Impl&` but `pimpl` after `return` has type `Impl*` which is incompatible.
2. `MyClass::GetName()` returns `const std::string&` but is non-const itself. (I'm not sure if this is allowed. I would never do so.)
3. I added a constructor/destructor because `pimpl` must be initialized with an instance.
4. I deleted copy constructor and copy assignment as default implementations  would break instances copying the `pimpl` pointer.
5. I moved implementation of `MyClass::GetName()` to solve the issue described by Ulrich.

Fixed sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class MyClass
{
protected:
    struct Impl;
    Impl *pimpl;
public:
    MyClass();
    ~MyClass();
    MyClass(const MyClass&) = delete;
    MyClass& operator=(const MyClass&) = delete;
#if 0 // WRONG:
    Impl& GetStruct() { return pimpl; }
    const std::string &GetName() { return pimpl->m_name; }
#else // BETTER:
    Impl& GetStruct() { return *pimpl; }
    const std::string& GetName() const;
#endif // 0

};

struct MyClass::Impl
{
    std::string m_name;
};

MyClass::MyClass(): pimpl(new Impl()) { }

MyClass::~MyClass() { delete pimpl; }

// Implementation after MyClass::Impl is defined
const std::string& MyClass::GetName() const { return pimpl->m_name; }

int main()
{
  MyClass myObj;
  std::cout << "myObj.GetName(): '" << myObj.GetName() << "'\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
myObj.GetName(): ''
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/db8f2d956bf24537)</kbd>

Note:

I replaced `std::w_string` by `std::string` which I consider as irrelevant change. (I've no experience with `std::w_string` but I guess, without the replacement, it wouldn't change anything.)